# How to read vlookup from PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've found that PHPExcel can read vlookup value if it starts with an alphabet, but when it comes to numbers, the value returns #N/A.

How can I make the PHPExcel read numbers value vlookup?

I tried changing the cell format of the vlookup table range to text, but that doesn't do anything.

Here's the code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $this->excel = $objReader->load($file_path);

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet

for($z=2;$z<=$arrayCount;$z++)
{                           
    $a = $allDataInSheet[$z]["A"];
    $b = $allDataInSheet[$z]["B"];  
    $c = $allDataInSheet[$z]["C"];                      

    echo "a: ".$a."<br/>";
    echo "b: ".$b."<br/>";
    echo "c: ".$c."<br/>";
}
```

the result:

```
a: #N/A
b: Orange Juice
c: Z02
```

the excel:

```
Code          Description      Item
------------  --------------   -----------
3000000073    Orange Juice     Z02
```

where column code and item are a vlookup formula, while description is an input text.